# Issues connected with update JsonStore ExtJs 3.4

Tags: json, extjs, jsonstore

I would like to display a window with details about error after user's request from combo box to server.If I've an exception,I put it in json object and send to cline side.Json object is like this.

```
 {
  {"error_message": "java.lang.NullPointerException: null"}    
  items: [] 
 }
```

this is part of my code where I send and receive data.I've tried to chatch data in every listerner of JsonStor but neither doesn't work,following is implemantation.I'm using ExtJs 3.4.

```
this.folderNameStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
            proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
                url: this.config.folderNamesPath,
                method: 'GET',
                timeout: 120000
            }),
            listeners: {
                beforeload: {
                    fn: function() {
                        var informaticaRepositoryId = this.getInformaticaRepositoryId();
                        if (informaticaRepositoryId) {
                            this.folderNameStore.setBaseParam('informatica_repository_id', informaticaRepositoryId);
                        }
                    },
                    scope: this
                }
            },
            root: 'items',
            idProperty: 'folder_name',
            fields: ['folder_name']
        });
        // Custom rendering Template
        resultTpl = new Ext.XTemplate('<tpl for="."><div class="informatica_workflow_command_folder_name-finder-item finder-item  x-combo-list-item">', '<h2 class="name">{folder_name}</h2>', '</div></tpl>');

        this.folderNameComboBox = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
            allowBlank: false,
            applyTo: "informatica_workflow_command_folder_name",
            disabled: true,
            displayField: 'folder_name',
            forceSelection: false,
            hideTrigger: false,
            mode: 'remote',
            itemSelector: 'div.informatica_workflow_command_folder_name-finder-item',
            listClass: 'job-agents-combobox',
            listEmptyText: helpsys.locale.javascript.no_matching_record,
            loadingText: helpsys.locale.common.searching,
            minChars: 4,
            submitValue: false,
            store: this.folderNameStore,
            tpl: resultTpl,
            triggerAction: 'all',
            typeAhead: true,
            maxLength: 80,
            maxHeight: 400,
            autoCreate: {tag: 'input', type: 'text', maxlength: '80'},
            valueField: 'folder_name',
            itemSelected: false,
            oldValue: '',
            listeners: {
                change: function () {
                    this.updateFolderNameComboBox();
                },
                select: function () {
                    this.updateFolderNameComboBox();
                },
                keyup: function() {
                    this.updateFolderNameComboBox();
                },
                scope: this
            }
        });

        this.updateFolderNameComboBox = function () {
            if (this.folderNameComboBox.value == '') {
                this.workflowNameComboBox.markInvalid();
            } else {
                if (this.folderNameComboBoxValue != this.folderNameComboBox.getValue()) {
                    this.workflowNameComboBox.markInvalid();
                }

                this.workflowNameComboBox.store.removeAll();
                this.workflowNameComboBox.lastQuery = null;
                this.workflowNameComboBox.enable();

                this.folderNameComboBoxValue = this.folderNameComboBox.getValue();
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a function that gets called on store load:
Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('folderNameStore').on('load', this.folderNameStoreLoaded);

And then in the function just do something like Ext.getStore('folderNameStore').proxy.reader.jsonData

And then you can do your pop up notice in an if statement like 
if (success == "error") { Ext.MessageBox.alert('Oh No', 'Oh No!.');}

Hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry don't have 3.4 but it looks like this might work:
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.StoreMgr